# Is there any rhyme or reason to where or when Set Items drop in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

The title says it all, basically I'm wondering if Set Items are more likely to drop from specific bosses, or are they just as likely to drop anywhere any other rare is likely to drop?

Note: I know bosses have more chances to drop magic items, but I'm more curious if certain sets are supposed to drop from certain bosses or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monsters have "Monster Levels" and some items only drop if a monster is within a specific Monster Level. I think these are called "Treasure Class" for the items. TC87 is the highest TC (Elite versions of items) and only drop from monsters with MLvl 87/88+. (Not sure of the exact numbers)

When an item drops, the game randomly decides on the quality (damaged, normal, superior), sockets, ethereality, if it will be magical, rare, set or unique. So the best chance of finding a specific unique item is to kill monsters which can drop normal or better quality of the item class and hope for the best. +Magic find items really help here.

Some areas in Hell have monsters where they are mostly MLvl 87+. The Pit in Act I, Diablo's Sanctuary in Act IV, Worldstone Chamber in Act V off the top of my head. So you have a good chance of finding every item in the game in those areas, without the difficulty of fighting Hell Baal. Although Hell Baal still has better chances of dropping the goods.

My favorite is Pindleskin, the unique undead warrior in the garden of Nilathak's (sp?) temple. He is only MLvl 86 so he can't drop every item, but he is super easy to kill and fast enough to access.

Also, you might think that TC87 uniques are the hardest items to find (not counting the high runes [f*ck you, Zod]), but TC3 uniques are (almost) just as hard (e.g. Torch of Iro, Wand). They are too low level to drop frequently in Hell, and the only place they drop frequently is in Act I Normal, but since the monsters are so low level, they don't drop uniques as often.

Comment: +1: High level bosses will not drop low level items, so if you're looking for the unique club, don't leave the first level.

Comment: +1 because you mention monster levels and TC. It might be obvious, but the accepted answer doesn't mention that you'll never find an item like [Immortal King's Soul Cage](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/sets/sets5.shtml#immortalking) except from a very few monsters/locations in the game.

Comment: @bumm For reference, I've upvoted this answer despite mine being the accepted, given that my original answer was done almost a year ago. Had the original question asked for the in depth details, I would not have been as quick to put what is essentially a "one liner" into the answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is no drop bias for sets. The only variables are Magic Find and Item Level (and obviously some monsters / bosses have a higher magic item drop rate).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: This might be nitpicking, but while there is no bias which makes set items *relatively* more or less likely to be dropped, there is one Set that can only be dropped in one area - the Cow King's Leathers!

Comment: @Grace Note Touche, I had forgotten about the infamous secret level set. Though also to be fair, I'm not sure anyone really wants that set for any true purpose other than as a trophy ;)

Comment: Can't argue there - I'm *still* hunting for the Swordback Hold, just so I can have it.

Comment: @Grace Note: You never found *that*? That's crazy :)

Comment: @bummzack I fell in love with it the first time I saw it on diabloii.net. I managed to get almost every other Normal Unique that I sought except the one I wanted most. Also more Gulls and Gnashers than I could ever care to hold.

Comment: @Grace Note: I think I found all the normal uniques there are. I think the one I really had a hard time finding was "Biggin's Bonnet".. now I really want to go play Diablo 2. Damn you ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that Hell difficulty *chests* as well as act bosses have a shot at the best treasure tables, including the Zod rune.

Answer (score -1):

Totally Random.

It does not matter for set items. For magical items, yes, the higher level creatures tend to drop more of them.

The most common way to get them is using a trainer (sadly).