# Is there a method to encourage set items to pop?

Tags: diablo-ii

In Diablo 2, is there a known method to encourage a particular item to show up?

I know that, in general, there is no way to increase the odds of getting a set item over a magic item, so magic find/barbarian item find and killing a lot of creatures is the general technique.

I have 2/3 of some sets and 2/5 of others.  Rather than get another piece of a set I can't use (nothing worse than popping a sorceress set while running a paladin), is there a way to encourage the game to pop the set you're trying to finish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/is-there-any-rhyme-or-reason-to-where-or-when-set-items-drop-in-diablo-2

Comment: @TheQ This wasn't specifically about increasing the odds of a set item appearing, as the other question was, but rather if there was any technique to increase the odds of an item from an already partially owned set once the original equation was satisfied.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After performing some research, it seems that the short answer is: no.

The best way to get a specific set item is to gamble on the appropriate item type, or kill monsters that can drop that item type (still, I wouldn't necessarily call this increasing the odds).

There used to be a site called D2Data.net that had excellent information on the drop percentage for various items. You can still access it using the [Wayback machine](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php). For example, say you wanted to find *Trang-Oul's Scales*, you could go to [the set's page](http://web.archive.org/web/20040202133813/http://www.d2data.net/) and click the link on the third row under the third column (this would be the item's TC, or [treasure class](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Treasure_Classes)). That would get you [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20040202133813/http://www.d2data.net/), where you can figure out what monster is your best bet for getting this item. Mind you, the chances listed there are only for a monster to drop the appropriate TC. The chance for getting a specific set item is even smaller.

To figure out just how much smaller, you will need to delve deep into [this item generation guide](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Item_Generation_Tutorial).

Comment: Awesome link, helps a lot ... I was surprised how high the council members on NORMAL rank for certain items.

Comment: @Stephen: Glad I could help.

Comment: Can you still get set items from gambling? I thought one of the later patches removed getting uniques from gambling? Also, doesn't the iLvl of the set item you want potentially result in some "sweet spots" for getting the drops?  I seem to recall that, for example, farming SoJ's isn't necessarily best done by killing Bhaal on the hardest difficulty at max level, but rather at lower level, on other specific bosses who drop closer to the target iLvl range.  (I apologize if this is detailed in any of the links you included, but they're blocked for me atm).

Comment: @Beofett: I imagine that most of what you said is buried deep in the last link I provided. That guide is really quite extensive. I am sad to say that I do not know whether or not D2Data.net took any of this into account, but people treated it as the ultimate source for drop rates, so I guess it's a relatively good lead for getting specific items.

Also, according to this (http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Gambling#Item_Quality_Determination) you can still get set items from gambling, at an abysmal rate.

Comment: @Stephen: I'll just point out that assuming my answer was sufficiently helpful, I'd appreciate if you go ahead and mark it as the answer (or tell me what you think is missing, conversely).

Answer (score -1):

The only other method that I have found to improve drop rates for set items is to find/buy/gamble the highest level armor (helmet, body, belt, boots, gloves) that are socketed with the most sockets possible and for use with your class. Then, using the horadric cube, transmute as high a lvl of topaz as you can get. Once you have enough high lvl topaz to fill all of the sockets on the armor you have collected, you can create an armor set that you can use to improve your "chance of finding magic items".. hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

The work around for gambling if you don't want to necessarily lose gold is to first save your progress then find the item you are looking to gamble on and then purchase it. If you should for some reason not want the item generated from the gamble hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> and end the task DiabloII which will allow you to end the game without saving allowing you to not lose your gold.

This may not be what you're looking for but it does work if you wish to try it.

Comment: this only works in offline mode.  In which case just use a char editor to give yourself the item

Comment: I still have yet to see set items generate from a gamble even when using this method.